# iostream no such file or directory

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Использую Codeblocks, выбрал язык C++ на компиляторе GNU GCC Compiler.
Видел множество подобных кодов, и у других они работают.

Может посоветуйте правильный чтоб оно скомпилировалось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Раз пишете на C++, то расширение файла должно быть `.cpp`, а не `.c`.

Comment: После смены расширения пишет "multiple defination of 'main" в шестой строке.

Comment: @MyrKLMnM Это уже другая проблема. Скорее всего у вас в проект добавлено несколько файлов с кодом с несколькими функциями `main`. Один проект - одна `main`.